# Create column based on dates in another dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to determine the tidal state of a dataframe `(DF)`

```r
DF <- data.frame(Date = c(2012-01-01 05:37:00,2012-01-01 05:50:00,2012-01-01 05:58:00), Tide= NA)
```

On the basis of the `Tides` dataframe below:

```r
Tides <- data.frame(Date=c(2012-01-01 05:31:00,2012-01-01 11:30:00,2012-01-01 17:58:00), Tide=c(low tide,high tide,low tide))
```

So I would like to divide the data into `low` and `high` tide on the basis of its closeness to `low` or `high` tide to the `Tide` dataframe.

I was trying to create intervals with more datapoints first in the `Tides` dataframe but I didn't succeed and I'm also not sure if that is the correct way to start

I would like to have this result, but the data is over several years so it can't be done manually.

```r
DF <- data.frame(Date = c(2012-01-01 05:37:00,2012-01-01 05:50:00,2012-01-01 05:58:00), Tide= c(low tide,low tide,low tide))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be done using `which.min` and I am finding the nearest time as per absolute difference. I have used `purrr` to do this operation row-wise.

I first converted the datetimes to POSIXct:

```
DF = DF %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date))

Tides = Tides %>% 
  mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date))
```

The code is below:

```
require(dplyr)
require(purrr)
DF = DF %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Tide = purrr::map_chr(.x=Date,~as.character(Tides$Tide[which.min(abs(Tides$Date-.x))])))
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot makeshift-programmer. Unfortunately I get the following error when trying your solution: Error: Result 4597 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0

Comment: This might be due to possible NA values. Can you check row 4597 of your data and post it here if you are not able to debug?

Comment: I checked it and there was indeed an NA so I deleted that row but now he gives me the same error message for other rows, e.g. 3745. There was no NA or anything in that row but I deleted it anyway (as well as the row before and after) and now he is giving me that same error for the row before 3753

Comment: Can you post the data in those rows? I will look into it.

Comment: When I wanted to copy the data I realized there were actually still some NAs but when I deleted them it finally worked!! Thank you so much!